# Trouble with connection to irc.freenode.net via Tor

Tags: linux, privacy, tor, irc

I have a trouble with connection to irc.freenode.net. I have set up Konversation IRC client according to guidelines:

- https://freenode.net/sasl/
- https://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml#tor

  Server: frxleqtzgvwkv7oz.onion
  Port: 6697, I have checked checkbox SSL.

  Connectivity:
   Proxy:
    Type: SOCKS5
    Host: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 9050

SASL authentication was enabled.

Screenshots:
[image]

But Konversation still can't connect to irc server.

Answer (score 0):

As announced in [various](https://twitter.com/freenodestaff/status/564848187710906368) [places](http://irc.netsplit.de/channels/details.php?room=%23freenode&net=freenode), freenode's Tor hidden service is currently down.